# how to save the list after add and remove elements in haskell?

Tags: list, haskell

I have a 3-tuple list of birthbook which contain name, month, day. I want to add new tuples and show the birthBook. However, after I add or remove values the birthBook does not change.
Say, after i add tom 5 6 but print birthBook just show "dd" 4 5, which means (tom,5,6) does not add in birthBook. what should i do?
here is my codes:

```
birthBook::[(String,String,String)]
birthBook=[("dd","4","5")]

prompt :: String -> IO ()
prompt todos = do
    putStrLn "Enter a command(add,remove,print)"
    cmd <- getLine
    interpret cmd todos
interpret :: String->String-> IO ()
interpret   "print"      todos= do
     print(birthBook)
     prompt todos
interpret   "add"        todos= do
    putStrLn "Enter a name"
    cmdname<-getLine
    putStrLn "Enter an integer month"
    cmdmonth<-getLine
    putStrLn "Enter an integer day"
    cmdday<-getLine
    print(add birthBook cmdname cmdmonth cmdday)
    prompt todos
add::(Eq key)=>[(key,v,z)]->key->v->z->[(key,v,z)]
add birthBook name month day = (name, month, day):birthBook

main= prompt []
```

Comment: You do not use `add` anywhere in your program.

Comment: Do you get `"dd" 4 5` only when you type the `print` command in your program, or also when you type the `add` command?

Comment: i only get dd 4 5 when i type print even though i add a new tuple. I want add a new tuple, and print all of them .

Comment: I want to add a new tuple in birthBook and print them but add function  seems that cannot "actual " add new tuple in birthBook.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you're forgetting Haskell is purely functional and does not treat values as mutable by default.

You need to pass the birthbook around as an argument to `prompt` and `interpret` in order for any changes to persist. You also were trying to print the initial declaration of `birthBook`, which will always remain the same as Haskell is a purely functional programming language and if you want to change anything, you need to make a new copy of your data plus the desired changes you're looking to make - hence the `let newBirthBook` expression I put at the end of your interpret routine.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Main where

birthBook::[(String,String,String)]
birthBook=[("dd","4","5")]

prompt :: [(String,String,String)] -> String -> IO ()
prompt bBook todos = do
    putStrLn "Enter a command(add,remove,print)"
    cmd <- getLine
    interpret bBook cmd todos

interpret :: [(String,String,String)] -> String -> String -> IO ()
interpret bBook "print" todos = do
  print bBook
  prompt bBook todos
interpret bBook "add" todos = do
  putStrLn "Enter a name"
  cmdname<-getLine
  putStrLn "Enter an integer month"
  cmdmonth<-getLine
  putStrLn "Enter an integer day"
  cmdday<-getLine
  let newBirthBook = add bBook cmdname cmdmonth cmdday
  prompt newBirthBook todos

add :: (Eq key) => [(key,v,z)] -> key -> v -> z -> [(key,v,z)]
add birthBook name month day = (name, month, day):birthBook

main= prompt birthBook []
```